# JS parse error about "<script>" tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing HTML and JS for a small site. When I write some special words in JS, I encounter a problem.

Here is the sample:

```
<script Language="javascript" >
    var template = {
                    "role":'<role name="" />',
                    "script":'<script>xxx</script>'
                   };
    ...
</script>
```

I found that Chrome will parse it wrong. It will ignore the JS text after the file `</script>` in the template declaration.

Comment: Tried this: '<' + '/script>' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser sees the `</script>` in your script as the end of the script tag, not as a string.  That means you are essentially trying to execute this:

```
<script>
  var template = {
      "role":'<role name="" />',
      "script":'<script>xxx
</script>
```

which is invalid JavaScript.

To avoid this, you need to split up your script tag:

```
"script":'<script>xxx</sc' + 'ript>'
```

so that the browser does not see the `</script>` and properly waits until your intended closing script tag.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

        var template = {
                           "role":'<role name="" />',
                           "script":"<sc"+"ript> type='text/javascript'>xxx"+"</sc"+"ript>"
                       };
    ......
    ......

</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any change except `type` attribute which is anyways not required if OP is using HTML5 doctype